# How to Change Global Variable With Function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a "Choose your own adventure" style game in Python where the user inserts various numbers that correspond with an action that will dictate what part of the story is told next. When the user inserts an invalid option, nothing I tried to make a function to simplify the endless if/else statements but I am having difficulties. I have a "step" variable that changes and leads to different circumstances and my function successfully changes the step variable but then the if/else statements don't trigger. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
step = 7

def stepchange():
  global step
  b = step
  while step == b:
    a = input()
    if a == 1:
      global step
      step = b + .1
    if a == 2:
      global step 
      step = b + .2
    if a ==3:
      global step
      step = b + .3

global step
if step == 7.1:
   print("Step 7.1")

global step
if step == 7.2:
    print("Step 7.2")

global step
if step ==7.3:
    print("Step 7.3")
```

Comment: As an aside, you only need `global step` once at the top of the function.

Comment: You never actually call the function. And comparing floats is dangerous... `float` is a binary fraction and not quite the same as its decimal representation. For instance, `7.1` passed through the formatter `{:.54f}'.format(7.1)` shows that it is `7.099999999999999644728632119949907064437866210937500000`. Consider using the `decimal` module instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the function, so no step changes happen. After calling, you may still have problems with later compares. `float`  is actually a binary fraction that is estimated, but not quite equal, in decimal. So, for instance, `7.1` is really `7.099999999999999644728632119949907064437866210937500000`. Since you are doing some math on those numbers you may find that rounding errors cause them to be a little different so the compare fails.

You can trim out extra unneeded `global` statements and use the `decimal` module:

```
from decimal import Decimal

step = Decimal('7')

def stepchange():
  global step
  b = step
  while step == b:
    a = Decimal(input())
    if a == 1:
      step = b + Decimal('.1')
    if a == 2: 
      step = b + Decimal('.2')
    if a ==3:
      step = b + Decimal('.3')

stepchange()

if step == Decimal('7.1'):
   print("Step 7.1")
elif step == Decimal('7.2'):
    print("Step 7.2")
if step == Decimal('7.3'):
    print("Step 7.3")
```

I don't know exactly what step is supposed to be, but if you are thinking step plus substep, a list may be a better choice:

```
step = [7, 0]


def stepchange():
  global step
  while True:
    a = int(input())
    if a in (1, 2, 3):
      step[1] = a
      break

stepchange()

if step == [7, 1]:
   print("Step 7.1")
elif step == [7, 2]:
    print("Step 7.2")
if step == [7, 3]:
    print("Step 7.3")
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `float` comparisons are tricky. Since you are getting text input, you might as well continue with text.

```
step = "7"

def stepchange():
    global step
    b = step
    a = input()
    if a == "1":
        step = b + ".1"
    if a == "2":
        step = b + ".2"
    if a =="3":
        step = b + ".3"

if step == "7.1":
    print("Step 7.1")
elif step == "7.2":
    print("Step 7.2")
elif step == "7.3":
    print("Step 7.3")
```